# Rails Paperclip - download file got corrupted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip for attachments

when i download file, it got corrupted.

File is download-able at production

```
send_file attachment.data.path, :type => attachment.content_type, :x_sendfile => true, :stream => false
```

it is working fine at local machine but it gives problem in production however i have set env as production

Comment: Please, tell what type of problems do you have with the file? How is it corrupted? How do you check it?

Comment: when file is opened it is blank, as it is not transferred completely, 1 byte received (IDM shows 0.00%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to check what is the file you are trying to send.

Add this line of code before your `send_file` statement:

```
logger.info "SENDING FILE: #{attachment.data.path.inspect}"
```

Then see the log, check the path and see whether the file really is there.

I suspect that your production and development modes have different database data *(and this is natural and expected)*, but the files saved in the filesystem are not in synchronization with the databases.

It is possible that there is some other difference between environments, but the path is the first thing I would consider guilty.

Comment: file type is pdf and inspect prints the correct path of the file, file is there. It also sends X-Sendfile header in production

Comment: Do you have the same server in production? Does your server understand the X-Sendfile header? For example for "nginx" you should use "X-Accel-Redirect" instead of "X-Sendfile".

Comment: server is apache and it is solved. the issue was in production server, there was some migration taking place that mixed up the correct paths